# Compliant to EN 303645 for iot board

Tags: iot

I would like to know how to be compliant to this point [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJTA3.png)

i am using esp32 without security features... From august 2024 every iot board should be compliant with that norm (EN 303645)..
I would like to know if i have respect the requirment somehow without adding a crypto element...

Thanks a lot